# how search engines (Google, yahoo, bing etc..) treat duplicate content pages

Tags: seo, web-crawler, google-search

I would like to know the methodology behind who the search engine treat the pages with duplicate content.

I general who search spiders calculate whether this content is original or the duplicate one.